# how to check the console.log output of devtools source code in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Have anyone known where is the output of console.log in the InspectorBackend.js of devtools code. I found the console panel in the chrome have no any output.

for example, I have set dumpInspectorProtocolMessages = true, and and also add console.error in the function _wrapCallbackAndSendMessageObject as following:

```
   console.error("show error on console");
   if (this.dumpInspectorProtocolMessages)
        console.log("frontend: " + JSON.stringify(messageObject));
```

I think the console panel in the chrome was loaded after above function, so where is the output, how to check it?

Btw, the function above is devtools source code, and what i want to see is the log output of devtools source code.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to see output of `console.log`'s located right into DevTools own source code, you need to open DevTools on DevTools. It's pretty easy:

1. Undock DevTools window. (This is important: otherwise step 2 won't be possible)
2. Right-click inside undocked devtools and click "inspect element".

This will open a second DevTools window which will be inspecting first DevTools; all the output from the first devtools frontend could be found there.

Comment: Hi, I right-click on the undocked devtools panel but I don't get "Inspect Element"! Please, give me more information about reproducing step 2. Thanks.  
Chrome v31.0.1650.57

Comment: I pressed Ctrl + Shift + J and got the second console.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome Hit `F12` on your keyboard and navigate to console tab   or right click on your page and click `inspect element`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `shift+ctrl+i`, it open  Developer Tools in Bottom and Find the `Console` tab  click to view the console logs

Answer (score 0):

In Google chrome use F12. For more check this link [Opening DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts#opening-devtools).

Comment: it can't work, and when use F12, it don't show any output of devtools source code.

Comment: go through this **[link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)** and i think you will get your answer.